# TypeScript: Overriding `any` with type in functions

Tags: typescript

A common problem that I've come across with some libraries, like `grpc`, is that the function interfaces are often the generic `any`. Is there a way in TypeScript to override `any` with a specific type?

For example, `grpc` has the following in the TypeScript definition:

```
export class ServerUnaryCall {
  /**
   * Indicates if the call has been cancelled
   */
  cancelled: boolean;

  /**
   * The request metadata from the client
   */
  metadata: Metadata;

  /**
   * The request message from the client
   */
  request: any;

  private constructor();

  /**
   * Get the endpoint this call/stream is connected to.
   * @return The URI of the endpoint
   */
  getPeer(): string;

  /**
   * Send the initial metadata for a writable stream.
   * @param responseMetadata Metadata to send
   */
  sendMetadata(responseMetadata: Metadata): void;
}
```

Any function that is of `ServerUnaryCall` will have the same fields, but I want to be able to override `request: any` with a specific type.

Is there a way to do this, even if it means rewriting the TypeScript definition to make it possible?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48690619/how-can-i-augment-a-property-within-a-third-party-typescript-interface-defined-a

Comment: Thanks @NathanFriend, I think that could get me closer. Ideally I'd have liked being able to do something like `myUnaryCall(call: ServerUnaryCall<MyType>, callback)` where I supply what my type is. I suppose the language doesn't support something like that?

Comment: TypeScript does support generics, but unfortunately the definition file for the library you're using (`grpc`) doesn't use them.  In this case, I think your only option is to write your own version of the definition file.

Comment: Better yet create a PR with the fix and submit it to DT for the rest of us :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to override an existing TypeScript definition file and change some of its declarations.  TypeScript does allow your to *augment* existing interfaces, but this ability is limited to adding content, not changing existing content.

However, as you mention, you could write your own TypeScript definition file; in this case you would have complete control over all of the types.

Here's some information about the augmentation process I mentioned above: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html