# How to augment Hapi.js server methods when using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, hapi

To augment `hapi` module to add type checking for server methods, following is the code:

```
import { Server } from 'hapi';

declare module 'hapi' {

    export interface Server {
        methods: {
            getUsername: () => Promise<string>;
        };
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work because `@types/hapi` package already defines `methods` as:

```
readonly methods: Util.Dictionary<ServerMethod>;
```

From this StackOverflow question, [As far as I know](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48690619/5723098), it is not possible to redefine the existing property. But I am not sure. I could not find any documentation about this. **If this is not the case, how can I augment/patch/fix the type info?**

As a workaround, I have created a new Hapi.js Server interface that extends the original interface. So instead of using hapi `Server` interface, I am using the one I created:

```
// src/augment.d.ts
import { Server as HapiServer } from 'hapi';

export interface Server extends HapiServer {

    methods: {
        getUsername: () => Promise<string>;
    };
}

// In my file src/server.ts file
import { Server } from 'src/augment';

// NOW IT TYPECHECKS CORRECTLY
const username = server.methods.getUsername();
```

**Is this the right approach to take?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While we can't modify the type of an existing field in an interface, we can modify the type of the field in this case. The type of the field is `Util.Dictionary<ServerMethod>`. While  `Util.Dictionary` is used in several places, the only place it is used with the type argument `ServerMethod` is for this member.

We can extend the `Dictionary` interface with the extra methods and have the methods only show up if the type parameter is `ServerMethod` (also we do a bit of magic insipider from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49927523/disallow-call-with-any/49928360#49928360) to not show the methods if `T` is `any`)

```
declare module 'hapi' {
    export namespace Util {
        type IfAny<T, Y, N> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? Y : N; 
        export interface Dictionary<T> {
            getUsername<T extends ServerMethod>(this: Dictionary<T> & IfAny<T, never, {}>) : Promise<string>;
        }
    }
}

let d = new Server({})
let f!: Util.Dictionary<any>;

d.methods.getUsername() // type checked
```

**Note**
Ideally there would be a dedicated type for `methods` that would allow us to add methods to it without extending the very generic `Dictionary` interface, but the typings are what they are right now. Someone could do a pull request to create a new interface for `methods`....