# How do I override the HTML attribute types for DOM elements in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com) in my project, which causes the `className` attributes for DOM elements to be rather long and sometimes even hold logic. To help with organisation, I'm using the [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) utility:

```js
const Foo: React.FC<{ bar: boolean, baz: number }> = ({ bar, baz }) => {
  return <div className={clsx("…", bar ? "…" : "…", baz < 10 && "…")} />;
  //                     ----
  //                     clsx: (...inputs: ClassValue[]) => string
};
```

By using the Babel [auto-import plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-auto-import) and declaring `clsx` to be a function in the global scope, I save a few precious keystrokes not importing the function in every file, but I want to save a few more by using a Babel plugin like [transform-jsx-classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-jsx-classnames), which will apply `clsx` to the `className` values automatically. TypeScript, however, doesn't know anything about the Babel plugin, so it is naturally unhappy with this:

```js
const Foo: React.FC<{ bar: boolean, baz: number }> = ({ bar, baz }) => {
  return <div className={["…", bar ? "…" : "…", baz < 10 && "…"]} />;
  //          ~~~~~~~~
  //          React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>.className?: string | undefined
  //          Type '(string | false)[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
};
```

It looks like I'll want to override the `React.HTMLAttributes.className` type to something like `any[]`, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I have my own `project.d.ts` file for importing the types of the auto-imported utilities to the global scope. I tried extending the React types there with only partial success — declaring custom attributes works, but I'm still unable to alter the existing `className` attribute:

```js
import _clsx from "clsx";

declare global {
  const FOO: boolean;
  const BAR: boolean;
  const clsx: typeof _clsx;
  declare namespace foobar {}
}

declare module "react" {
  interface HTMLAttributes {
    className?: any[]; // Doesn't work
    customAttr: number; // Works!
  }
}
```

```js
const Foo = () => {
  return <div />;
  //     ~~~~~~~
  //     Type '{}' is not assignable to type
  //     'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.
  //
  //     Property 'customAttr' is missing in type '{}' but required in type
  //     'HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.
  //     ts(2322)
  //
  //     project.d.ts(…): 'customAttr' is declared here.
};
const Bar = () => {
  return <div className={["foo"]} customAttr={0} />;
  //          ~~~~~~~~~
  //          HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>.className?: string | undefined
  //          Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  //          ts(2322)
  //
  //          @types/react index.d.ts(…):
  //          The expected type comes from property 'className' 
  //          which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<…>'
};
```

How do I get TypeScript use my `className: any[]` type instead of React's `className?: string | undefined`?

Comment: After returning to this some time later, [I found this answer to another question that essentially says that something like this isn't possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48692419/11308378) but I'm still trying to find something more "official" (e.g. TypeScript documentation or discussion on GitHub) that confirms it.